# Generic Types incompatible with given method signature?

Tags: java, generics, javafx, jfxtras, reification

Given the following method:

```
public <E> void bindContentBidirectional(final String fieldPath,
        final String itemFieldPath, final Class<?> itemFieldPathType,
        final ObservableList<E> list, final Class<E> listValueType,
        final SelectionModel<E> selectionModel,
        final String selectionModelItemMasterPath)
```

Am I correct in my understanding that, if I have an `ObservableList<PrintablePredicate<SomeClass>>` as the type of the:

```
final ObservableList<E> list
```

(that is, `E = PrintablePredicate<SomeClass>` that this can never work because for the next argument:

```
final Class<E> listValueType)
```

I can only write PrintablePredicate.class and not PrintablePredicate.class as generic types are not reified. In other words, the given method signature for bindContentBidirectional is incompatible with all E such that E has generic type arguments.

Putting it all together in a concrete code scenario, say we have:

```
@FXML private CheckListView<PrintablePredicate<Miner>> profileConditions;      
private MinerMonitorProfile minerMonitorProfile;

private void initialize() {
    BeanPathAdapter<MinerMonitorProfile> minerMonitorProfileBPA = new BeanPathAdapter<>    (this.minerMonitorProfile);
    minerMonitorProfileBPA.bindContentBidirectional("conditions", null, String.class, this.profileConditions.getItems(), PrintablePredicate.class, null, null);
}
```

the compiler says:

> The method `bindContentBidirectional(String, String, Class<?>, ObservableList<E>, Class<E>, SelectionModel<E>, String)` in the type `BeanPathAdapter<MinerMonitorProfile>` is not applicable for the arguments (`String`, `null`, `Class<String>`, `ObservableList<PrintablePredicate<Miner>>`, `Class<PrintablePredicate>`, `null`, `null`)

Is there anyway around this? Thanks!

Note: `this.profileConditions.getItems()` returns type: `ObservableList<PrintablePredicate<Miner>>`

Further note that parameterizing the method call as in:

```
minerMonitorProfileBPA.<PrintablePredicate<Miner>>bindContentBidirectional("conditions", null, String.class, this.profileConditions.getItems(), PrintablePredicate.class, null, null);
```

does not alleviate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have that kind of issues (casting a plain class to a parameterized one?) I use double casting, in order to bypass the compiler complain.

So in your case I guess you could write

```
(Class<PrintablePredicate<Miner>>)(Class<?>) PrintablePredicate.class
```

when passing the *PrintablePredicate.class* parameter to the bindContentBidirectional function.

---

**Edit:** I found out that simply casting PrintablePredicate.class to Class (I don't undestand why though, it seems kinda unnecessary on my opinion since *.class are already of type Class) or assigning it to a variable before passing it to the method works for this case (using javac 1.8.0_25). Therefor maybe you should just use this instead of the code above:

```
(Class)PrintablePredicate.class
```

So your error might be due to a compiler bug similar to this one from OpenJDK (yeah, which doesn't make sense because it's a bug): https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028682

---

As a summary then after my findings, this "double casting" trick stuff (or just assigning an object to a variable) can help you "make it easier" for the compiler to "understand" your code when it has a bug such as this one seems (lol, it's kind of funny having to do that I guess, but it just shows you that sometimes you cannot even trust the compiler).

Comment: That did indeed work. Thanks very much. By chance do you (or someone else) have any resources where I could learn about this seemingly magical double casting? Thanks =)

Comment: Unfortunately I've never read about it, it's just a trick I found out one day when struggling with that kind of issue. I'm gonna add some more info to the answer trying to explain what the trick does.

Comment: Hmm... to be honest, I think it's just some sort of hack I found, because the code seems to also work if you first assign the class to a variable (such as using "Class clazz = PrintablePredicate.class" before the method call) and then just pass that variable to the method. So I wonder if this compilation error is in first place some sort of bug from the java compiler.

Comment: And now I seem to have found that in this case simply using "(Class)PrintablePredicate.class" when passing the parameter should do the work. :/

Comment: I appreciate very much your elaborating on your findings. If anyone could perhaps clarify why this is so confusing that would be great. =)